# Reverting a specific file to origin/master

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a feature branch (say - `new_feature_branch`). I have already changed a set of file and all my changes are `commit` and then `push` to a remote git repo (say `origin/new_feature_branch`). But now I want only a specific file (say `specific_file`) of `new_feature_branch` revert back to (`origin/master`). How can I do this? I've tried -

```
git checkout origin/master specific_file name
```

But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Checkout `origin/master`, copy the file's contents into a text editor, checkout your branch, and paste them back in?

Comment: Try `git checkout origin/master -- specific_file_name`.  Perhaps the command is being misinterpreted, and the `--' will clarify the intent.  This command should work fine though.

Comment: If your commits are tidy, you can use git cherry-pick <commit>